# Unexpected output when using fseek

Tags: c

Assuming we have a text file named hi.txt that contains the following string:

> AbCdE12345

Let say we run this code:

```
int main() {
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("hi.txt","r");
  if(NULL == fp) { return 1; }
  fseek(fp,-1, SEEK_END);
  while (ftell(fp) > 0) {
     printf("%c",fgetc(fp));
     fseek(fp,-4, SEEK_CUR);
  }
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

When I ran this code it printed: `3EbCd`

When I tried to guess what it would print I thought that it should be 52d.
Can anyone explain what has happened here ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like there is a non-printable end-of-line character at the end of your file. That's what gets printed first. Then the position is moved in turn to `3`, `E`, and `b`. At this point, re-positioning by `-3` fails, because the location would become `-2`. File cursor stays where it was, i.e. at `C` which gets printed next. The following attempt at repositioning fails too, so `d` gets printed. The next repositioning succeeds, terminating the loop.

To detect situations when `fseek` is ignored, check its return value, like this:

```
while (ftell(fp) > 0) {
    printf("%c",fgetc(fp));
    // Successful calls of fseek return zero
    if (fseek(fp,-4, SEEK_CUR)) {
        // Exit the loop if you can't jump back by 4 positions
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For files opened in text mode the offset passed to [`fseek`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/) is only meaningful for values returned by [`ftell`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/ftell/). So the offset may not necessarily be in bytes. Try opening the file in binary mode:

```
fp = fopen("hi.txt", "rb");
```

and see if the results are different.